# Making android app work with a python web server

Tags: android, python, eclipse

I have a small android application made in eclipse.

Now i need to build a web server with python so they could work together.

Should i make a new python projekt then in some way link it to my application?
Or 
Should i use jython and rebuild the app in a jython project?

I have used Visual studio before, and eclipse is not my hometown, så i would really appreciate clear answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a clue about how the android app and the web app are supposed to work together...

You can (theoretically) use just any language and techno you find appropriate for the web app since the communication between the android app and the web app will be http requests / responses.

Also, you can use whatever code editor you want to write Python code, as long as it (the code editor) supports Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kivy to write Python apps that work on Android (as well as just about any other system). Python, they say, has a built in module that you can easily make a web server with. I'm about to try it, I believe.

See
* kivy.org
* http://m.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python